# emacsclient opens a file and does eval simultaneously

Tags: emacsclient

I know that emacs can open a file while evaluating an expression:

```
emacs file --eval "(toggle-frame-maximized)"
```

However I failed to replicate this with emacsclient:

**1.emacsclient can open a file:**

```
emacsclient file
```

**2.And it can also evaluate an expression:**

```
emacsclient --eval "(toggle-frame-maximized)"
```

**3.But a problem happens when the two are put together:**

```
emacsclient file --eval "(toggle-frame-maximized)"
```

It starts to report error and does not open the file. 
So is it possible to use emacsclient to open a file while still do eval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several attempts I think I found the solution, basically just put everything into eval and concatenate them use progn:

```
emacsclient --eval "(progn (find-file \"file\") (toggle-frame-maximized))"
```

Comment: According emacsclient's manual, when `--eval` is given, the arguments are interpreted as a list of expressions to evaluate, so you can also use `emacsclient --eval "(find-file \"file\")" "(toggle-frame-maximized)"`.

Comment: This method of just evaluating `find-file "file"` is great and simple (which is important). However, it has the disadvantage that the buffer is not considered a "server-editing-buffer", so some of the nice in-built emacsclient machinery does not work — for example, when you call `emacsclient -c --eval "(find-file \"file\")" "(other-elisp-functions)" `, and then close the frame, the buffer you just opened is not killed (irrespective of whether it was open before or not), unlike with `emacsclient -c file`.

Comment: I think that using `server-visit-files` — e.g. `(server-visit-files '(("file" . nil )) proc)` — might be a solution, except that we'd need to know the process id of the client, which I have no idea how to get.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `--eval` option for `emacsclient` you could just add your elisp code to `server-visit-hook` in its customization buffer. This way you still get the normal behaviour of returning to the shell after exiting the server buffer.